# Copy multiple ranges and paste

Tags: excel, vba

EDIT: I forgot to put all the code.

I'm trying to copy 2 ranges and paste them to a different sheet but i get this error:

> Object variable or With block variable not set

**Code:**

```
Sub Test()

    Dim R1 As Range
    Dim R2 As Range
    Dim mRange As Range
    Dim C As Range
    Dim LastRow As Integer

    LastRow = Sheets("Errors").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set R1 = Range("D5:N5")
    Set R2 = Range("B8")
    Set mRange = Union(R1, R2)

    For Each C In mRange.Areas

        C.Copy
        Worksheets("Errors").Range("A" & LastRow + 1).Paste

    Next C

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Where is `Lastrow` being Calculated ? Even `mRange` is not being assigned to any Range.

Comment: Can you add in your code a text description of what you want to achieve in that line ?

Comment: @Mikku right, i forgot to add that part of the code, i've updated it.

Comment: Change `LastRow` to `Long` type. Also, you would want to clarify the worksheet `R1` and `R2` are expeceted to be on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim R1 As Range
    Dim R2 As Range
    Dim mRange As Range
    Dim C As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long 'Change "Integer" to "Long" because "Long could take a high value in case you have vast amount of data

    With ThisWorkbook 'Add "ThisWorkbook." to avoid conflicts if you have open more than one workbook

        With .Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Declare from which sheet you want to set ranges
            Set R1 = .Range("D5:N5")
            Set R2 = .Range("B8")
            Set mRange = Union(R1, R2)
        End With

        For Each C In mRange.Areas

            C.Copy

            With .Worksheets("Errors")
                'Lastrow should be calculated here in order to get the new last row every time you paste something
                LastRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                .Range("A" & LastRow + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With

        Next C

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your input, it was very helpful too.

Comment: @DiegoDuarte glad to hear that. If you find the answer helpful, vote the answer to help others with the same question.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added any ranges to `mRange` & then you are trying to access it.

Add the ranges to `mRange`:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim R1 As Range
    Dim R2 As Range
    Dim mRange As Range
    Dim C As Range
    Dim LastRow as Integer

    LastRow = Sheets("Errors").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set R1 = Range("D5:N5")
    Set R2 = Range("B8")

    Set mRange = Union(R1, R2)

    For Each C In mRange.Areas

        C.Copy Worksheets("Errors").Range("A" & LastRow + 1)

    Next C

End Sub
```

Comment: sure, i've added this code:

`Set mRange = Union(R1, R2)`

And i get the same error, this is the right way to add the ranges to my variable?

Thanks !

Comment: Can you set a break point & step through to see where it is failing? Check out the change to the `C.Copy` line too.

Comment: thanks, i've changed the method .Paste to .PasteSpecial and apparently iys working now, thank you very much.